# If $G=G_0\geq \ldots\geq G_n=\{1\}$ then $\displaystyle|G|=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} |G_i/G_{i+1}|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group and $G=G_0\geq \ldots\geq G_n=\{1\}$ a normal series of $G$. How can I show $$|G|=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} |G_i/G_{i+1}|,$$ that is, the order of $G$ is the product of the orders of the factors?

My approach was using induction on $n$ but I can't see how to apply the inductive hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then index$[G:H]=|G|/|H|$.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem =)